# How to use Enyo 2.0 WebService object

Tags: javascript, web-services, chromium, enyo

I am building a Campfire client that will run in WebOS and as a Chrome desktop web app.
I have the following code:

```
logIn: function(){
    this.apiToken = this.$.loginScreen.$.apiToken.getValue();
    this.subdomain = this.$.loginScreen.$.subdomain.getValue();
    this.fullURL = 'https://' + this.subdomain + '.campfirenow.com/';
    this.$.roomService.url = this.fullURL + 'rooms.json';
    var response = this.$.roomService.send({'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.apiToken, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': this.subdomain + '.campfirenow.com'});
```

The 'roomService' is like this:

```
{name: "roomService", kind: "enyo.WebService", url: null, onResponse: "successfulAlert", onError: "someFailure"}
```

And in Chromium I keep getting the following XMLHttpRequest error:

```
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this StackOverflow question:

[XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

You're being blocked by trying to run this from a file:// URL.

Comment: and to add, if you were running it from a server, you may still be blocked if Campfire didn't allow cross-site access to their APIs over AJAX *OR* the user's browser doesn't support cross-site AJAX semantics.

Comment: I am running from Chromium with the security features disabled. Maybe I can embed a node.js server into my app and make calls that way? I'd much rather just use the webservice somehow.